# powershell, CommonParameter alias preventing parameter name resolution

Tags: powershell

say I have a script named `Test.ps1` starting with

```powershell
[CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter()][alias('foo')]$Foobar,
        [parameter()][switch]$Fool
    )
```

when at the command prompt I entrer `Test.ps1 Foo` and hit the `Tab` key, as expected, PS will rotate between `Foobar`, `Fool` and `foo` (with a lowercase `f` to be sure it's the alias, not `Foo` that I typed on the command line)

but, if instead my script starts with

```powershell
[CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [parameter()]$Event
    )
```

hiting the `Tab` key after `Test.ps1 Ev` will have PS stuck on `Test.ps1 ev`, the alias for `ErrorVariable` (I doublechecked displaying `$PSBoundParameters`, it is `ErrorVariable`)

`Test.ps1 E` will get stuck on `Test.ps1 Event`, never suggesting `ev`

is this special behaviour with CommonParameters' alias by design? or a bug? is there a workaround?

### context

```
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.4046
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.19041.4046}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.4046
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: I suspect it's a bug in Windows PowerShell - PSReadLine correctly cycles through `ev`,`Event` in PowerShell 7